# TCHAR end of line character

Tags: string, visual-c++

```
int DownloadFtpDirectory(TCHAR* DirPath) { 
WIN32_FIND_DATA FileData;  
UINT a; 
TCHAR* APP_NAME = TEXT("ftpcli"); 
TCHAR* f;
int j = 5;
do {
  j++;
  f = _tcsninc(DirPath, j);
}while (_tcsncmp(f, TEXT("/"), 1));
TCHAR* PATH_FTP = wcsncpy(new TCHAR[j], DirPath, j);
```

After the last line gets a string in which there is no line ending character, how to fix this?
P.S.  how to do so would be out of line "ftp://ftp.microsoft.com/bussys/", get a string ftp.microsoft.com if both strings are TCHAR ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TCHAR* PATH_FTP = wcsncpy(new TCHAR[j+1], DirPath, j);
PATH_FTP[j] = TEXT('\0');
```